# Writing tuples within tuples into a file

Tags: python-3.x, file, nested, tuples

I have a list of tuples within a list of tuples, like this:

a = [(3.140829166, ('a', '96')), (3.141596483, ('b', '96')), (3.193681724, ('c', '99')) ...]

I would like to write this into a file like this:

> 3.140829166   a   96
>
> 3.141596483   b   96
>
> 3.193681724   c   99
>
> and so on...

So the matter being the conversion of the tuples to strings and floats to strings withing the conversion of tuples to strings. I have tried the join method, but it somehow didn't work (perhaps incorrect usage).

```
c = ('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(y[0],y[1]) for y in x[1])
a = ('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(x[0],c) for x in a))
    
f2.write(a)
```

Than you in advance for a reply.

Comment: Show your code, please

Comment: If you suplement c for x[1] in the second line it works fine and removes the outer tuple (the inner remains).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do  like this,

```
data_to_file = '\n'.join('{} {} {}'.format(str(i),j[0],j[1]) for i,j in a)
fp = open(file_name,'w')
fp.write(data_to_file)
fp.close()
```